# Gradle, War, tomcat and manifest

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm trying to run a war file how it's provided in documentation. I do:

```
$ ./gradlew -Pprod war
$ java -jar  ./build/libs/jhipster-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war --spring.profiles.active=prod
no main manifest attribute, in ./build/libs/jhipster-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

When I add Main-Class atribute to the war block:

```
war {
    baseName = 'jhipster'
    version =  '0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.jhipster.web.Application'
    }
}
```

I get "Error: Could not find or load main class com.jhipster.web.Application"

It is said in spring-boot gradle plugin documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-gradle-packaging that it should find the Application class with main() method but somehow MANIFEST.MF contains only one line:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: Repackage as a jar file not a war. You could try deploying to tomcat as a test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `war` task doesn't run Spring Boot's repackaging task so you're left with a traditional unexecutable war file that doesn't have a `Main-Class` attribute in its manifest.

Try running `build` or `bootRepackage` instead:

```
$ ./gradlew -Pprod bootRepackage
```

Comment: "./gradlew -Pprod bootRepackage" did the trick, war seems to be running with java -jar .... however .war.original still not. So, what should I do? Report a bug in documentation or bug in spring build tools?

Comment: `.war.original` is the war file before Spring Boot has repackaged it. It's not intended to be run with `java -jar`. As you can run the `.war` file with `java -jar`, everything is working as expected